# Making sure that UIView autoresizes as specified in NIB settings

Tags: iphone

I have create a view based application and its loaded correctly what i designed in the xib files.My doubt is when i designed uiview it has the property of resize its frame size(autoresize).

But when i loaded the application into iphone the uiview has not the property of resize its frame automatically.Is it possible to change a uiview automatically in iphone (when application loaded)? (or)  We can change the frame size of the uiview for every touches moved event.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Are you able to post some code of what you currently have set up?

Comment: I didnt write any code so far its a empty screen changes its frame ...Thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried something like this:

```
CGRect f = self.view.bounds;
f.size.width = 200; // change value here;
f.size.height = 200; // and here

self.view.bounds = f;
```